# Python "FileHandler" to Azure BlobStorage - is there no such thing

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I had the situation in which I had a pretty large SAS file (300GB) in a blob storage that needed to be processed in a Azure ML Service workspace. They main task was to convert it to a bunch of parquet files.

Of course, I could download the file to the FileShare Container of the Azure ML Workspace and then process the file using pandas read_sas() with an appropriate chunksize defined:

```
    local_file_path = "./dld/mysas.sas7bat"
    with open(local_file_path,"wb") as local_file:
       downloader = blobclient.download_blob()
       downloader.readinto(local_file)
    
    reader = pd.read_sas(local_file_path, format='sas7bdat', chunksize=1000000)

    count = 0
    prefix="chunks/testchunk"
    chunk: pd.DataFrame
    for chunk in reader:
        count += 1
        name = prefix + str(count) + ".parquet"
        chunk.to_parquet(name, engine = "pyarrow")
```

This of course is working. However, I was hoping that there would be a more efficient way. Like being able to create a "filestream" directly from the blobstorage. Without the need to first download it into the mounted Azure File Share. But I haven't found anything. So I wrote my own "stream-wrapper" for a blob storage:

```
class BlobStorageFileHandler(RawIOBase):

    def __init__(self, storageDownloader: StorageStreamDownloader):
        self.downloader = storageDownloader
        self.chunks = self.downloader.chunks()
        self.current_pos = 0
        self.current_chunk_len = 0
        self.current_chunk = None
        self._read_next_chunk()

    def _read_next_chunk(self):
        self.current_chunk: bytes = next(self.chunks, None)
        if self.current_chunk is None:
            self.current_chunk_len = 0
        else:
            self.current_chunk_len = len(self.current_chunk)

    def seekable(self) -> bool:
        return True

    def seek(self, offset, whence=SEEK_SET):
        print("seek: ", offset)

    def readable(self) -> bool:
        return True

    def read(self, size=-1):
        end_pos = self.current_pos + size
        
        # if more bytes are requested that are left in the current read bytes-chunk
        if end_pos > self.current_chunk_len:
            # number of bytes that have to be read from the old chunk
            rest_part = self.current_chunk_len - self.current_pos
            # number of bytes that have to be read from the next chunk
            new_part = end_pos - self.current_chunk_len

            old_chunk_end: bytes = b''
            if rest_part > 0:
                old_chunk_end = self.current_chunk[self.current_pos: self.current_pos + rest_part]

            self._read_next_chunk()

            new_chunk_part: bytes
            # if there was no further chunk left to be read
            if self.current_chunk is None:
                if rest_part > 0:
                    return old_chunk_end
                return b''
            
            if self.current_chunk_len > new_part:
                new_chunk_part = self.current_chunk[0: new_part]
            else:
                new_chunk_part = self.current_chunk

            self.current_pos = new_part
            return old_chunk_end + new_chunk_part
        else:
            result = self.current_chunk[self.current_pos:self.current_pos + size]
            self.current_pos += size
            return result
```

With this class, it is not necessary to first download the data to the mounted FileShare (or to any local directory, if used on-premise):

```
    sas_file = BlobStorageFileHandler(blobclient.download_blob())
    reader = pd.read_sas(sas_file, format='sas7bdat', chunksize=1000000)
```

This is just a first solution and not very sophisticated, but it works as expected.

However, I cannot imagine that I am the only one having this need, therefore, I wonder if there other solutions or existing wrapper classes, like the one I showed above.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Thanks
Hansjörg

Answer (score 1):

You can download blob in chunks using [`download_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#download-blob-offset-none--length-none----kwargs-) method as well. Basically you will need to specify `offset` (starting location) and `length` (number of bytes to read) parameters and the method will only return those bytes to you.

In your current implementation, since you're not specifying these parameters the SDK is downloading the whole blob.